# Let $a,b,c \in [0,1[$ such that $a+b+c=2$. Prove that $a^3+b^3+c^3+2abc\leq 2$

Tags: real-analysis, algebra-precalculus, analysis, inequality

> Let $a,b,c \in [0,1[$ such that $a+b+c=2$. Prove that
> $$a^3+b^3+c^3+2abc\leq 2$$

**My attempt:**

put $a=x^{\frac{2}{3}}$,$b=y^{\frac{2}{3}}$,$c=z^{\frac{2}{3}}$

\begin{align*}
&x^{2}+y^{2}+z^{2}+2x^{\frac{2}{3}}y^{\frac{2}{3}}z^{\frac{2}{3}} \\
&\quad \leq x^2+y^2+z^2+\frac{2}{3}(x^{2}+y^{2}+z^{2})\\
&\quad =\frac{5}{3}(x^{2}+y^{2}+z^{2}),
\end{align*}

because $\frac{a+b+c}{3}\geq (abc)^{\frac{1}{3}}$. And

\begin{align*}
\frac{5}{3}(x^{2}+y^{2}+z^{2})
&= \frac{5}{3}(x^{\frac{1}{3}} \cdot x^{\frac{5}{3}} + y^{\frac{1}{3}} \cdot y^{\frac{5}{3}} + z^{\frac{1}{3}} \cdot z^{\frac{5}{3}}) \\
&\leq \frac{5}{3} \sqrt{x^{\frac{10}{3}} + y^{\frac{10}{3}} + z^{\frac{10}{3}}}\sqrt{x^{\frac{2}{3}} + y^{\frac{2}{3}} + z^{\frac{2}{3}}}\\
&= \frac{5\sqrt{2}}{3}\sqrt{x^{\frac{10}{3}} + y^{\frac{10}{3}} + z^{\frac{10}{3}}}
\end{align*}

Now I need to find a good frame to $\sqrt{x^{\frac{10}{3}}+y^{\frac{10}{3}}+z^{\frac{10}{3}}}$, or $\sqrt{a^5+b^5+c^5}$ for make

$$ \frac{5\sqrt{2}}{3}\sqrt{x^{\frac{10}{3}}+y^{\frac{10}{3}}+z^{\frac{10}{3}}}\leq 2. $$

**I have two question:**

1. **Is my attempt correct?** (I mean if my algebraic manipulation is true.)
2. **Can you find a good frame** to $\sqrt{x^{\frac{10}{3}}+y^{\frac{10}{3}}+z^{\frac{10}{3}}}$, or $\sqrt{a^5+b^5+c^5}$ for make
   $$\frac{5\sqrt{2}}{3}\sqrt{x^{\frac{10}{3}}+y^{\frac{10}{3}}+z^{\frac{10}{3}}}\leq 2 \quad ?$$

If you have an other method, you can post it, but it will be nice if you can complete my attempt.

Comment: If $a$ and $b$ are close to $1$ (so that $c=2-a-b$ is close to $0$), then $\frac{5}{3}(x^2+y^2+z^2)$ is close to $\frac{10}{3}$ (which is of course larger than $2$). So, there is no hope that your approach will prove the proposed inequality. To see why this happens, note that the original inequality becomes an equality as one of $a$, $b$, or $c$ goes to $0$. On the other hand, the AM–GM inequality will cause the quantity to increase a lot when $a, b, c$ differ a lot.

Comment: Also, you must make use of the condition $a, b, c < 1$ somewhere in your solution, for otherwise the inequality is false only with the constraints $a,b,c\geq 0$ and $a+b+c=2$.

Comment: Following on @SangchulLee's comment, is the right-side bracket intended to be inverted? If it's not a typo, what is it intended to mean?

Comment: @EricSnyder: the reversed square bracket denotes the open end of an interval in many countries. So $[0,1[$ means the same as $[0,1)$.

Comment: @TonyK Thanks for the heads-up. I did not know about that convention.

Comment: @Sangchul Lee thank you sir ,nice information

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**New proof**:

Using $0 \le (1 - a)(1 - b) = 1 - a - b + ab$, we have $ab \ge a + b - 1$.

We have
\begin{align*}
 &a^3+b^3+c^3 + 2abc\\
 \le\,& a^2 + b^2 + c^2 + 2abc\\
 =\,& (a + b)^2 - 2ab + c^2 + 2abc\\
 =\,& (a + b)^2 - 2ab(1 - c) + c^2\\
 \le\,& (a + b)^2 - 2(a + b - 1)(1 - c) + c^2 \\
 =\,& (2 - c)^2 - 2(1-c)(1-c) + c^2 \\
 =\,& (2 - c)^2 - (1-c)^2 + c^2 - (1-c)^2\\
 =\,& 1 \cdot (3-2c) + (2c-1)\cdot 1\\
 =\,& 2.
\end{align*}
We are done.

---

**Old proof**:

WLOG, assume that $c = \min(a,b,c)$.

Using $0 \le (1 - a)(1 - b) = 1 - a - b + ab$, we have $ab \ge a + b - 1$.

We have
\begin{align*}
 &a^3 + b^3 + c^3 + 2abc\\
 =\,& (a + b)^3 - 3ab(a + b) + c^3 + 2abc \\
 =\,& (a + b)^3 - ab(3a + 3b - 2c) + c^3\\
 \le\,& (a + b)^3 - (a + b - 1)(3a + 3b - 2c) + c^3\\
 =\,& c^2 - c + 2\\
 \le\,& 2.
\end{align*}

We are done.

Comment: Note to anyone confirming this: it is correct, but the second but last step is a nuisance due to all the signs and cancellations, I got $8-12c+6c^2-c^3-6+11c-5c^2+c^3$ out of that expression. Is there an easier way to do it?

Comment: @SuzuHirose I added another proof.

Comment: @River Li nice proofs,thank you

Comment: @anaas You are welcome.

Comment: @River Li ,I spend my free time proving some inequality,i need to learn some theorems and tools about inequality,Do you know a book that discusses inequality in detail?

Comment: @anaas The Cauchy-Schwarz Master Class?

Comment: @River Li
In order to get started with this book 'Do I have to be fluent in calculus, because I'm still studying calculus ?

Comment: @anaas Some parts require no calculus.

Comment: okey,thank you again

Answer (score 0):

Hint :

Using :

$$a^3+b^3+c^3-3abc=(a+b+c)(a^2+b^2+c^2-ab-bc-ca)$$

And $$(a+b+c)^2=a^2+b^2+c^2+2ab+2bc+2ca$$

We got :

$$8-6(ab+bc+ca)+5abc\leq 2$$

You can conclude using uvw's method .

Comment: I don't think this way works, I tried this but didn't get the end result.

Comment: @SuzuHirose No it works or you are not aware about the uvw's method .

Comment: Yeah, I didn't get there from this, probably my mistake. River Li's method worked out though.